# NodeJs MYSQL Sequence bulk insert best practice

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a list of data that will be inserted into a MySQL database using nodejs.
I`ve written the code as:

```
con.connect(function (err) {
     myArray.forEach((el)=>{
        con.query(1stQuery,1stValue,(error,result)=>{
        //dosomething with result
           con.query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();",(error2,result2)=>{
                myArray.child.foreach((el2)=>{
                    //insert child into an array after processing 
                    //keep counter of for each, when every child is looped do insert

                       con.query(2ndQuery,ArrayOfValue,(error3,result3){
                        //when everything is finished then send some data back to user
                       })

                })

             })

        })
    })
}
```

everything works fine but it's just too slow. I'm currently testing in a local server using xammp and inserting about 400 entries of parent data and 800 entries of its child took about 60 seconds.
Is there any way I can improve the runtime performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should prepare the query and reuse it for every insert. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries
2. You should use a transaction for the bulk inserts. This greatly improves performance, as MySQL does not have to commit after every insert.

Comment: thank you very much transaction kinda slipped my mind there because i thought it wouldn't work with last_insert_id and nodeJS it worked fine now :D